# How to add permanently a table with cells in ckEditor

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

I'm rubbish at Javascript and a newbie with ckeditor...

I need to add a table with cells to the ckeditor but not from the editor itself. Basically I want the table to appear in ckeditor when users open ckeditor. So they can fill the table with information.

This is similar to what I want to do: http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/plugins/sourcedialog/sourcedialog.html

If you look at the editor you can see some text there already.

I can see that ckeditor uses iFrame so I tried to find the iFrame code in order to add my table code to it but I cannot find it.

Anyone will be able to help please?

Answer (score 0):

The content that is already in the `<textarea>` element when the user opens the page containing CKEditor is there because it's simply provided in the HTML of this page. Open the source of the page that you quote and you will see:

```
<textarea cols="80" id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="10">
    This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.
</textarea>
```

Just a note: the sample you referred to was for CKEditor 4.3 beta, it was released in 2013, and you should use the latest stable version (which is 4.4.7 now).

You can also use one of the following two CKEditor features:

- [Content Templates](http://ckeditor.com/addon/templates) plugin – Lets you create predefined templates that can be loaded to editor content.
- [Widgets](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets) – Special rich content units with a predefined structure, where you can decide which parts are editable etc. Read more here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets

Comment: Hello Anna, thank you for your help! I have tried to but inside <textarea> still won't allow html...

Comment: Your HTML code needs to be encoded as in my example (see `&lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;`). If you update your question with your code it will be much easier for others to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Hello Anna, so far I have this:

Comment: <div class="col-sm-9">
<textarea class="form-control counted" id="recipedescription" name="recipe_description" placeholder="" rows="5" style="margin-bottom:10px;" parsley-required="true" autocomplete="off"> </textarea>  
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'recipedescription' );
</script>
</div>

Comment: And if I use the encoded html inside <textarea> it will still be plain text, no bold or anything.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help you write your page for you if you are unwilling to include the relevant source code of your solution in your question (and I won't repeat this again). Check the samples from CKEditor SDK, like the [one with the table](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/table.html). You can get its simplified source code down below ("Get Sample Source Code"), you can use your browser's View Source feature to see the source code of the full sample, table included. Try to use this in your solution and if this does not work, then you are doing something differently and you are not sharing it.